# Can't PyCharm automatically suggest function or class names?

Tags: pycharm

For example, I am typing the following:

```
X, y = make_blobs()
```

While Pycharm red flags "make_blobs" as unresolved references, it don't automatically suggest which library or package it should import, in this case, it is:

```
from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs
```

It's hard for users to remember exactly which dependency it should import. In IntelliJ or Eclipse, the IDE automatically find it for you.

Is there any setting in PyCharm that can enable this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

PyCharm documentation on [Auto Import](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PYH/Auto-import) feature.

On Windows, click on the red squiggle and do keystroke ALT+ENTER. Suggested imports appear on the top of the popup, click on a suggested import and the import is added at the top of the file, taking into account any existing imports. See screenshot.

[image]

**Or**, click on the red squiggle and wait (a second or so) for the red light bulb to show in the left gutter. Clicking on the red light bulb shows the same popup as described above. It will also show the keystroke shortcut as a tooltip. See screenshot.

[image]